# How to jump to a specific view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 3 views (xib'd) the third view opens a modal view (also xib'd).
My goal is to dispose the modal view and jump on the view #1.

I used the following code but it does nothing.

```
self.statusView = [[StatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.statusView animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:
```

I also tried the following, same result. 
[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

I'm going crazy...

statusView has an accessor regularly synthetized and it represents the view that I want to jump to.

Answer (score 7):

It is not entirely clear how your views are set up with respect to each other, based on what you've said so far.

I'm guessing you have a navigation controller, and 3 view controllers that are displayed on the navigation stack.

If that's the case, and you want to pop back by two screens at once (from #3 to #1, skipping #2), then you need a pointer to the view *controller* for #1 (not the view itself).  It looks as if the first `popViewController:` method call in your question is sending in a view.

Sample code to pop to the first view controller:

```
UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
UIViewController* controller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If you've tried this, and it doesn't work, a few things might be going wrong:

- Maybe `self.navigationController` isn't actually the right object.
- Maybe the view you expect isn't actually view #0 on the navigation stack.
- Maybe the navigation controller you're working with isn't currently visible.

Here are some further steps you can take to test these hypotheses:

- When you first allocate the navigation controller you want to work with, call `NSLog(@"Nav controller is at %p", navController);` and in this code add a call to `NSLog(@"Now my navController is at %p", navController);` and check that the addresses match.
- If the nav controller is the right one, print out the current navigation stack; something like this (which assumes each view controller has a different class name):

  ```
  for (UIViewController* viewController in navController.viewControllers) {
    NSLog(@"%s", class_getName([viewController class]));
  }
  ```
- Do something visual to the navigation controller you think is visible to make sure it actually is.  For example `[navController.visibleViewController.view addSubview:aColorFulView];` where `aColorFulView` is some visually obvious `UIView`.

Comment: this actually very helpful let me try to follow up on this - thank you this is good, even if I don't get around to find out what's going on because of my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

-popToViewController lets you pop controllers OFF the stack. What you want to do is *push* new viewControllers ONTO the stack, so use:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController: self.statusView animated: YES];`